# How to call a function using Dash with callback using Inputs/States that aren't explicitly defined as input

Tags: python, visualization, plotly-dash

I'm using Dash to read from a JSON and create a number of input fields based on the data it ingests, and visualise the results. I'd like to have function that will create a JSON when the form is submitted by button press, taking the values of all the input fields as States.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import json

app=dash.Dash
output = []
in2 = []


for (x,y) in data.items():
    in2.append(State(x, 'value'))
    output.append(html.Label(y['constraint_name']))
    if y['constraint_type']=='fs':
        output.append(dcc.RadioItems(id=x,
                                    options=[
                                        {"label" : "On", "value" : "On"},
                                        {"label" : "Off", "value" : "Off"}
                                    ],
                                    value = "On"
                                    ),)
    elif y['constraint_type']=='dur':
        output.extend((html.Br(),dcc.Input(id=x,
                                        type='number',
                                           value=10,
                                        min=0
                               ), html.Label("People ")))
    output.extend((html.Br(), html.Br()))

output.append(html.Button('Submit', id='submit'))
output.append(html.Div(id="div2"))

app.layout = html.Div(output, style={'width': '44%', 'display': 'inline-block', 'vertical-align': 'top'})

@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='div2', component_property='children'),
    in2
)
def update_output_div(input_value):
    teststring1 = ""
    for val in input_value:
        teststring1 += val

    return 'You\'ve entered "{}"'.format(teststring1)
```

The app does not run with callback in the above state, but will take list `in2` if it has just `Input('1','value')`. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

The key here is to pass your state in a list as the third parameter. The rule is that outputs go as first parameter, inputs as second and states as third. Both the inputs and states have to be passed in lists. Furthermore you have to make sure that for every input and state your callback function has to take a parameter. So in your case you have to do something like this:

```
@app2.callback(
    Output(component_id='div2', component_property='children'),
    [Input('1', 'value')],
    [State('2', 'value')]
)
def update_output_div(input_value1, input_value2):
    ....
```

Keep in mind that if you have your second input value as state it will not trigger the callback function on change. To make it trigger the callback on change it has to be declared as an input and put in the list with the other input.

Comment: I understand, however the list I have used here is a test, it's actually 100s of id's, so this method is not practical. I'm looking for a way to add a list that can be created programmatically

Comment: You're probably interested in creating your own dash components at this point -- put your callbacks into react -- @Wf19